# NSObject Subclass Initiation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, initialization

Here is my predicament:
I have a tableview controller that loads a detail view on selection.  I have a custom class declared as so in the detail view.

```
Match *myMatch;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Match *myMatch;
```

When I load the view from the tableview, i set the value of the match to pre initialized match like so: (there might be syntax errors because i did not copy and paste)

```
Match *match = [[Match alloc] initWithMatchData:[profile.matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[detailView setmyMatch: match];
```

But when I access the variable myMatch from within the detail view it is null.  I think I am doing something wrong.  Something along the lines of initializing the myMatch object.  I don't initialize it.  do i need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setmyMatch` should be `setMyMatch` (upper case `M`)
2. You need to synthesize `myMatch`